# Verify if the 'Ip' field value in one table is within the IP ranges of another table using ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I've a table in Clickhouse to store server logs

```
CREATE TABLE DDBB.LogTable
(
    `ip` String,
    `fecha` Date,
    `path` String,
    `code` UInt32,
    `size` UInt32,
    `referer` String,
    `UA` String
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(fecha)
ORDER BY fecha
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192


INSERT INTO DDBB.LogTable (ip,fecha,`path`,code,`size`,referer,UA) VALUES
 ('66.249.74.10','2023-09-06','domain.com/a',200,43491,'"-"','"Mozilla/5.0"'),
 ('16.22.43.176','2023-09-06','domain.com/a',200,45739,'"-"','"Mozilla/5.0"'),
 ('16.22.43.176','2023-09-06','domain.com/c',200,49552,'"-"','"Mozilla/5.0"');
```

And other table to store ip ranges

```
CREATE TABLE DDBB.Ip
(
    `ip` String
)
ENGINE = Log

INSERT INTO DDBB.Ip (ip) VALUES
 ('66.249.79.160/27'),
 ('66.249.74.0/27'),
 ('66.249.79.224/27'),
 ('66.249.79.32/27'),
 ('66.249.79.64/27');
```

I want get rows in DDBB.LogTable where ip is contained in some range from table DDBB.Ip

In this example the result desired is the first row, because only first Ip is contained in some of Ip ranges of table Ip:

```
('66.249.74.10','2023-09-06','domain.com/a',200,43491,'"-"','"Mozilla/5.0"')
```

My SQL is

```
SELECT 
    t1.ip ,t2.ip as range,if(isIPAddressInRange(t1.ip, range)=0,'not','yes') AS inRange
FROM LogTable AS t1, Ip AS t2
where inRange = 'yes'
```

But this SQL is inefficient and becomes very slow when there are millions of rows in the table

[Here a example](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/681bb762-7680-4c89-81f2-90c16999f1d2)

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [clickhouse IPv4 and IPv6 function documentation](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/ip-address-functions)? What have you tried?  Will you need to support both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses? Have you read yo on how IPv4 subnet masks and IPv6 prefixes work? Do you know how to compare an address to a masked/prefixed range?

Comment: Yes, I know IPv4 and IPv6, my best SQL is

SELECT 
    t1.ip ,t2.ip as range,if(isIPAddressInRange(t1.ip, range)=0,'not','yes') AS inRange
FROM LogTable AS t1, Ip AS t2
where inRange = 'yes'

Here a complete example https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/aff9cb1b-de9f-48c8-8a52-4cdc96bf324b 

But this SQL is inefficient and becomes very slow when there are millions of rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

for t2 better will

use engine=Join

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/join

or engine=Dictionary

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/dictionary
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/dictionaries#range_hashed

look examples in https://github.com/AlexeyKupershtokh/clickhouse-maxmind-geoip